# sorting files in a directory into subdirectories based on size

Tags: bash

so I have a directory filled with files (text files). I want to sort them into different subdirectories based on their file size.

For e.g., if its greater than **1MB -> `large_files`**. If its less than **1MB -> `small_files`**.

I would like to be able to change the directory path (the input/target) and it will create the subdirectories automatically (if they dont exist).

I am very confused on how to approach this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you tried and at which point you are confused. You will find many answers here if you split up your task... 1. loop over files in directory 2. get file size 3. create directory 4. move files.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
dir=${1?Please specify the directory to sort}
cutoff=${2:-1048576} # bytes

cd -P -- "$dir" || exit
mkdir -p -- small_files large_files || exit

find . ! -name . -prune -type f '(' \
  -size "+${cutoff}c" -exec sh -c 'exec mv -- "$@" large_files' sh {} + -o \
                      -exec sh -c 'exec mv -- "$@" small_files' sh {} + ')'
```

On a GNU system, you can pass the `-v` option to `mv` and `mkdir` to make it more verbose. With GNU tools, it can be simplified to:

```
#! /bin/sh -
dir=${1?Please specify the directory to sort}
cutoff=${2:-1M}

cd -P -- "$dir" || exit
mkdir -p -- small_files large_files || exit

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f '(' \
  -size "+$cutoff" -exec mv -t large_files {} + -o \
                   -exec mv -t small_files {} + ')'
```

With that `-t` option to specify the target directory, we no longer need to invoke `sh` to insert the list of file names in the middle of `mv`'s arguments.

You can add more categories like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f '(' \
  -size +1M   -exec mv -t large_files  {} + -o \
  -size +100k -exec mv -t medium_files {} + -o \
              -exec mv -t small_files  {} + ')'
```

With `zsh`, you could also do it like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
dir=${1?Please specify the directory to sort}


cd -P -- "$dir" || exit

for size target (
  LG+1   huge_files
  LM+100 very_large_files
  LM+1   large_files
  LK+100 medium_sized_files
  L+100  small_files
  ''     tiny_files
) {
  mkdir -p $target || exit
  files=(*(NDoN.$size))
  (($#files == 0)) || mv -- $files $target || exit
}
```

Comment: this works. could you explain it a bit if possible? how would I add more subfolders if I want? for example, one for medium files between 500kb to 1mb? Small for under 500kb and large for 1mb? Im a bit confused.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is doing + or - and does not account for the case when the file size is exactly the size stipulated.  (e.g. -size +1M and -size -1M leave out the case of -size 1M). That's why in my solution, I use ! to negate the size searched for since it includes the equals to case.

Answer (score 0):

```
not= && while :; do 
 while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
  [[ -z "${not}" ]] && target="large_files" || target="small_files"
  [[ ! -d "${target}" ]] && mkdir "${target}" 
  mv "${f} "${target}/${f}"
 done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ${not} -size +1000k -printf "%f\0" 2>/dev/random)
 [[ -n "${not}" ]] && break 
 not=!
done
```

The outer `for` loop dynamically changes the find size from greater than 1M to less than or equal to 1M. Errors are redirected to `/dev/random` (presuming you are on Linux, adds to entropy - change it to `/dev/null` if you don't have `/dev/random`).

The target directory is changed to large_files before `${not}` is set and the target directory is created if it does not already exist. The next iteration sets `${not}` to `!` and finds files who are not greater than 1M (less than or equal to) and likewise creates the directory small_files if it does not already exist.

The files are moved to their corresponding directories.

After `not` is set the first time, the inner loop logic is run once more after `not` is set then the loop is broken.

Note: the null byte is utilized for while loop processing because it is more robust, `IFS=` desets the internal field seperator for processing null byte separated lists and `-d ''` sets the delimiter to the null byte, `-r` protects backslashes from being stripped/interpreted.

Comment: Note that `1000k` is 1024000 which is neither 1MiB (1048576) not 1MB (1000000). `1000k`, `-maxdepth`, `-printf` are already GNU extensions, you can just as well use `-size +1M` (for 1MiB). `-size +1000000c` for 1MB would be standard.

Comment: Note that `IFS=` is to prevent stripping leading and trailing SPC, TAB, NL characters (which are in the default value of `$IFS`), it's not about NUL delimited records.

Comment: As you're using `-printf '%f\0'` instead of `-print0`, that means that arguments to `mv` may start with `-`, so you should use use `mv --`. Note that while both `-printf` and `-print0` are GNU extensions, the latter (as opposed to the former) is now found in several other implementations, so using `-print0` would make it more portable (in addition to work around problems with leading `-` in file names)

Comment: Instead of that `while` + `break` approach, you can do `for not in '' !`. (and use `${not:+"$not"}` instead of `$not` for it to work even when `$IFS` contains `!`).

Comment: IFS stands for "Internal Field Separator", I mentioned that in the answer. The rest of your suggestions are minor.